# Subspaces and Bases - Vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

[image: Question]

In regards to the question, im confused because M is saying y is greater than x and positive, and N is saying that x is greater than y but is negative, so the union of the sets would be what?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: i think with the usual laws , it's just a set .it's not a subspace.
did you see the definition of a cone?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do draw a picture and it's became easy

$[1,1]\in M$ and $[0,-2]\in N$ the summ of this two vectors are not in $P$